# Store Varray [PL/SQL]

Tags: plsql

Creating the varray:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ListaCursos IS VARRAY(10) OF Cursos;

DECLARE
    listaCursos1 ListaCursos;
    c1 Cursos;
    c2 Cursos;
    p_ref REF Profesor;
    p_ref2 REF Profesor;
BEGIN
    SELECT REF(p) INTO p_ref FROM Profesorado p WHERE p.codigo = 3;
    c1 := NEW Cursos(1, 'Curso 1', p_ref, 20, '01/06/2011', '01/07/2011', 30);
    SELECT REF(p) INTO p_ref2 FROM Profesorado p WHERE p.dni='51083099F';
    c2 := NEW Cursos(2, 'Curso 2', p_ref2, 20, '01/06/2011', '01/07/2011', 30);
    listaCursos1 := ListaCursos(c1, c2);
END;
/
```

Trying to use it:

```
CREATE TABLE Alumnado OF Alumno;

DECLARE
    a1 Alumno;
    a2 Alumno;
    listaCursos1 ListaCursos;
BEGIN
    a1 := NEW Alumno(100, '76401092Z', 'MANUEL', 'SUAREZ IBAÑEZ', 'M', '30/6/1990', listaCursos1(1));
    a2 := NEW Alumno(102, '6915588V', 'MILAGROSA', 'DIAZ PEREZ', 'F', '28/10/1984', listaCursos1(2));
    INSERT INTO Alumnado VALUES (a1);
    INSERT INTO Alumnado VALUES (a2);
END;
/
```

And now it shows this error:

DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at line 6

Comment: You are trying to read from uninitialized collection. `listaCursos1(1) <- error`.

Comment: I initialized it in the other block, how can i store it?

Comment: How long do you need this values (`listaCursos1`) ? Only for these inserts?

Comment: I need to use them in other blocks.

Comment: I've add answer But I advise redesign your code and simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create package specification.

```
create package  test_pkg 
is 
 g_listaCursos1 ListaCursos; 
end;
```

In first block add

```
   test_pkg.g_listaCursos1  := ListaCursos(c1, c2);
```

In second read values from package spec.

`test_pkg.g_listaCursos1(1) , test_pkg.g_listaCursos1(2)`

Restriction:

- Package variables are accessible in the same session

Answer (score 0):

If you create a type inside a PL/SQL block, it'll be available only inside that block. So the `VARRAY` you create inside the first block is available only inside that block. You can either create a standalone type which will be stored in the database until you drop it or you can create a type inside a package and refer the type through the package. For more information you can read the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00503)

Comment: Are you getting error for `ListaCursos` or `LISTACURSOS1` now?

Comment: Now when i try to use the values it shows: identifier 'LISTACURSOS1' must be declared. And if i declare listaCursos1 "listaCursos1 ListaCursos;" it shows: Reference to uninitialized collection.  I will edit the first post to show the code.